# NtOpenFile returns STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_INVALID

Tags: c++, winapi

Following code tries to spawn a file handle using NtOpenFile :

```
HANDLE spawnFileHandle(){
HANDLE ret;
IO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock;
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes;
ObjectAttributes.SecurityDescriptor=0;
ObjectAttributes.SecurityQualityOfService=0;
ObjectAttributes.RootDirectory=0;
ObjectAttributes.Attributes=0;
ObjectAttributes.Length=sizeof(OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES);

WCHAR stringBuffer[5048];
UNICODE_STRING  string;
string.Buffer = stringBuffer;
lstrcpyW(stringBuffer, L"\\??\\");
lstrcatW(stringBuffer, EXEPath);
string.Length = lstrlenW(stringBuffer)*2; // Edit after comment.
string.MaximumLength = 5048;
ObjectAttributes.ObjectName=&string;
NTSTATUS error=origZwOpenFile(&ret, FILE_READ_DATA, &ObjectAttributes, &IoStatusBlock, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0);
printf("huh %ls %x", stringBuffer, error);
return ret;
}
```

but it allways returns STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_INVALID, example :

Edit : [HBIP] - Hidden Because Im Paranoid -.-

```
EXE path : C:\Users\n00b\Desktop\[HBIP]\Debug\[HBIP].exe
huh \??\C:\Users\n00b\Desktop\[HBIP]\Debug\[HBIP].exe c0000033
Spawned Handle : cccccccc
```

What could be the reason ?

Comment: Well, asterisk is not a valid filename character. Also, `UNICODE_STRING::Length` is in bytes, not characters. Also, you generally should set `OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE` in OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES::Attributes.

Comment: the asterisks are for masking the path ;)) but the second one i just assumed its the __string__ length o0 however changing it to bytes changes nothing, still same error. I think thats not the problem cause it would return "file not found" not "name invalid"...

Comment: Correction, second is the answer :) i multied by 4 not 2 thanks, please post as answer.

Comment: I'm guessing there are invalid characters in `EXEPath`. If it's not an asterisk, then it's `\n` or something (a forgotten backslash?). Replace `EXEPath` with a literal.

Comment: Ah, an odd-length string, huh? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UNICODE_STRING` structure expects both `Length` and `MaximumLength` to be in bytes. Note that these values will always be even.

You're getting `STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_INVALID` because your `Length` is an odd number, therefore invalid.

Comment: Also beware that sizeof() will *not* work to get the length in bytes because it includes the null terminator and the Length member doesn't want it. Good: `lstrlenW(path) * sizeof(wchar_t)`   Bad: `sizeof(path)`

Comment: UNICODE_STRING details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380518(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: `RtlInitUnicodeString()` is in fact designed to initialize this struct for you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648420(v=vs.85).aspx